# View Pager Indicator in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to create an indicator (view pager indicator) at the bottom of the page just as we have for the books on Google play.

I know there is a lot of information and a common answer about Jake Wharton's library and samples.

I just wanted to confirm about the alternative work around if I don't wanna go for a 3rd party library.

thanks.

Comment: What would you like to confirm? It exists, and it works, and there's plenty of tutorials on the web for it too.

Comment: @MattTaylor: I know..that this library pretty much works and there is no doubt about it but my requirement does not want to have a third party library. Hence, wanted to know if there is any other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just wanted to confirm about the alternative work around if I don't
>   wanna go for a 3rd party library.

An alternative work around then would be manually to create the indicators, listen for `onPageSelected()` callback of `ViewPager` and change the indicators.

Indicators could be represented by a `LinearLayout` with multiple `ImageViews` created dinamically. Dinamically because the number of indicators should match the number of pages in `ViewPager`. Changing an indicator state then would mean to change the `ImageView` at a particular postion with something that makes it appear as "selected".

But, think twice if you really need this overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to `<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip/>` element.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```